# MySQL: Get all Columns of Table starting with name "ctr_" and value 1

Tags: php, mysql

I have a country restriction on products in my shop and a slow query to select all country-columns with a value of `1` from the table product.

1. I select all active countries in my shop:

   ```
   $ids = select id from country where active = 1;
   ```
2. Then I select all countries, which are active in a product:

   ```
   foreach $ids as $id { select ctr_{$id} from product where ctr_{$id} = 1;
   ```

Is there a faster way to get the columns starting with `ctr_*` and which value is equal to `1`?

Comment: Do you really want to query column names, or do you instead want to get some data from your table?  This is not clear to me.

Comment: Hello and yes, I want to get only the column_names in a product row where the column_name starts with ctr_ and the value is 1.

Comment: With the following I get all the columns_names: SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
  FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
  WHERE `TABLE_NAME`='product' AND `COLUMN_NAME` LIKE 'ctr_%'; but I only want the columns with value 1

Comment: I think you will need dynamic SQL for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
// first get the columns
$query = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='product' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'ctr_%'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($conn),E_USER_ERROR);
$cols = Array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) $cols[] = $row[0];

// then build the query
if(count($cols))
{
  $query = 'SELECT '.implode(',', $cols).' FROM product WHERE 1 IN ('.implode(',',$cols).')';
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($conn), E_USER_ERROR);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($conn,$result))
  {
    // do something with the row
    // ....
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you. Almost the same I use in my first thread. The number of columns in the table countries are identical to product and "ctr_*";

Comment: I want to avoid the foreach, because it's slow when a list of products is long.

Comment: Is it possible that the title of your question is wrong ? Because this answer does exactly what the question asks - it gets all columns whose name begins with `ctr_` and then fetches all rows which contain value 1 for at least one of these columns.

Comment: Yes and no. I do it in almost the same way and wanted to ask, if there is a faster way. I have forgotten "faster" and added it now.

Comment: What in the above code runs slow on your PC ? By the way the best practice is to convert columns into rows - i.e. instead of having a column for each country, use 2 columns only (VALUE and COUNTRY_ID) and then list all countries in a separate look-up table. Would make your life simpler.

Comment: I know, it's not the usual way, but I can't change it. I have to find the fastest solution: Each Country can be activated for each product, so that I can take all countries and run a foreach to get the columns with value 1. Right.  But in a product list (maybe 200) it's working very long to get the active countries. Therefore I asked for a faster way.

Comment: Where did you see the command `foreach` in the answer ? Do you understand what the code does ?